# JQuery Selecting an element within a for each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So the last line of code selects all the "a" elements on the page that are within "transactiontable".
I need it to only select the "a" element that lies with the current "tr" element as each URL for each "tr" element is unique.

Currently all the URLs have the same id value as from the last iteration of the for each function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Ignore "[[ @{'~' + ${flowExecutionUrl}(_eventId='existingVehicle')} ]]" as that is Thymeleaf.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
            $('#items-list tr').each(function() {
                var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
                var url3 = "\u0026id=" + id;

                var url = [[ @{'~' + ${flowExecutionUrl}(_eventId='existingVehicle')} ]] + url3;

                $('.transactiontable a').attr('href', url);
            });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#items-list tr').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
        var url3 = "\u0026id=" + id;

        var url = [[ @{'~' + ${flowExecutionUrl}(_eventId='existingVehicle')} ]] + url3;

        $(this).find('.transactiontable a').attr('href', url);
    });
});
```

The '$(this)' selector represents the current item within the scope of the iterator, and 'find' then performs the selection within that element.

Comment: A few words explaining what you're doing and why would make this a better answer.

Comment: Ah thank you! I had to edit out the ".transactiontable" part though for it to work. $(this).find('a').attr('href', url); Will mark as answer when 9 minutes are up.